# Creating a python formula that subtracts from each array

Tags: python-3.x

I have created the following in excel that I am trying to replicate.

Column A show the date
Column B has a binary indicator that can take the value 1 or 0
Column H is the running total of Column B

Now the tricky part:
Column C returns the date of when the cumulative total of the indicator is 1 (value of C2), for the start date corresponding to that row.

e.g. In cell C3, the corresponding start date is 01-Jan and for that date the indicator is 1, so it returns 01-Jan.
However for cell C5, we are looking at 03-Jan onwards, and the first date the total of the indicator reaches 1 is 09-Jan, and this value is returned.

Column D returns the date of when the cumulative total of the indicator is 2 (value of D2), for the start date corresponding to that row.

e.g. In cell D3, the corresponding start date is 01-Jan and when we start on that date, the cumulative total of the indicator reaches 2 on 09-Jan.
In cell C24, we are looking at 22 January onwards, and the first date the total of the indicator reaches 2 is 24-Jan.

The same goes for columns E, F, and G.

[image: Image of my spreadsheet[][1]]

[image]

Comment: Did you try something? If not, please try some code and if you face any errors/issues then post it here in SO.

Comment: I can do it using for loops but that it is taking quite a while. In terms of other code, I am not sure where to start. With excel, for each row, I am subtracting the cumulative total of the previous row to form a new array in the ($H$3:$H$25)-$H4 for example, I am not sure how to do that here.